# Magento connect manager showing login screen in console

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, magento-connect-manager, console

Magento connect manager showing login screen in console.

I have installed 1.9.1.0 ver of magento, Want to upgrade my extension. But when i select any extension version for upgrade and click on commit changes button. It scroll me to console area and shows login page of connect manager instead of console window. After putting credential of connect manager it gives message that "No actions selected". But all these functionality is working fine on Local side.
[image: Please see the image of console is showing login form of connect manager]
Please help me.

Comment: Currently i can't see that login screen, But for next time whenever i saw that screen then i'll check first your link and the accept it, Thank you Baby in Magento.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a answer for your problem. you can try this link :

http://gondo.webdesigners.sk/wp-content/extensionDownloader.php

enter the extension url & select the version and download it & than manually add files through FTP. But Before installing new version take beckup of your old extension.

because all customization related to extension you will lose once you installed new one.